# How to design RF amplifier with dual emitter transistor

Tags: rf

I have a bipolar dual emitter transistor BFP840(Infineon) and want to design a common base amplifier at 5GHz, but I don't know how to lay it out because a resistor is connected to its emitter. Should I open one of the emitters?

Comment: You need to run your spill chicker before submitting your post. Then you need to add capital letters, punctuation and spaces in the right places. This is site policy. [Write to the best of your ability](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on the site's help pages.

Answer (score 1):

Your part has two emitter pins on the package, but that does not make it a dual-emitter transistor. The two emitter pins are simply both bonded to the single emitter of the semiconductor device (one of them most likely through the semiconductor substrate).

Probably part of the reason is to provide very low impedance grounding for the emitter when used in common-emitter configuration.

If you want to use this device in common-base configuration, you will lose whatever benefit this provides, and probably not achieve the same performance that is available in common-emitter configuration.

If you do go ahead anyway, you should connect the two emitter pins together in your circuit.

Comment: What's the point of connecting two emitter pins, can I just leave one floating? I have a trace underneath the transistor blocking the path.